# Code to print all the lines that have more than 5 characters

Tags: c

I'm trying to write code which is supposed to print all lines which have more then 5 characters, and I don't know where the problem is in my code.  Can you help?

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
  int i, s, n ;
  char c, t[100];
  n=0;
  puts("start taping lines");
   while(c=getchar()!=EOF)
   {
   s=0;

   while(c!='/n')
   {

    ++s;
    }
    if (s>=5){
    t[n]=c ;
    ++n;
    }
   }

          puts("lines >80 char =/n");
           for(i=0;i<=n;++i)
           {
               printf("%s /n",t[i]);
           }
  return 0;
}
```

Comment: 1) Use meaningful variable names. 2) Learn to properly indent your code, which makes it much easier to follow the flow of execution. 3) Learn to use a debugger to step through the code to see exactly what it is (and is not) doing. 4) Learn to describe a problem more clearly than *I don't know where is the prob?*

Comment: Use proper variable names (more than one letter and meaningful) and indent/space your code correctly will help greatly in debugging. RIght now it is difficult to tell what this does.

Comment: You have an infinite loop at while(c!='/n') , and it's supposed to be \n

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
char *line;

if (strlen(line) >= 5)
    printf(line);
```

Look for strlen() function in C library.

Answer (score 0):

> code who suppose to print all lines wish have more then 5 char

Rather than save the entire line in `t[100]`, which may be too small anyways, simply save up to 5 characters.  Print them when at least 5 characters encountered and then and all subsequent characters.

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void) {
  int c;  // Use int here.
  unsigned char buffer[5];

  unsigned n=0;
  puts("start taping lines");

  // This assignment to c is the result of `getchar()!=EOF`  (i.e. 0 to 1)
  // while(c=getchar()!=EOF)

  while((c=getchar()) != EOF) {
    if (n >= 5) {
      putchar(c);
    } else {
      buffer[n++] = c;
      if (n == 5) {
        printf("%.5s",buffer); // print first 5 characters.
      } 
    }
    if (c == '\n') {  // Use `\` not `/`
      n = 0;   
    }
  }
  return 0;
}
```

Comment: what buffer stand for and ty again